# C++ aligned new[]

Tags: c++, c++17, memory-alignment

#### Overview

When browsing [operator new, operator new[] - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), it seems we have a number of options for allocating arrays of objects with specific alignment requirements. However, it is not specified how to use them, and I can't seem to find the correct C++ syntax.

Can I somehow make an explicit call to this operator, or will the compiler automatically infer the overload? :

```cpp
void* operator new[]( std::size_t count, std::align_val_t al );
```

Looking at [Bartek's coding blog](https://www.bfilipek.com/2019/08/newnew-align.html), it seems like the compiler will automatically choose an overload based on whether or not the alignment requirement is larger than `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` (which is usually 16 on 64-bit machines).

#### Question

Is it possible to manually choose an overload for the `new` operator in some cases? Sometimes I might want an allocated block to be aligned in a certain way (I assume the alignment to always be a power of 2, and likely larger than 16).

#### Choice of compiler

I'm probably going to be using GCC and C++ >= 17 for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Define "certain way". Also explain *why* as this sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: Certain way could be 32 byte alignment. I don't see anywhere specifying how it is possible to achieve that if I want an array of objects. Is it an XY problem? I'm reading a book where they write about this, so I wanted to implement it and test it out. I just wanted to know if it was possible at all using the `new[]` syntax.

Comment: What are you allocating that needs that kind of alignment? Is this something [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) could solve?

Comment: The book is called Game Engine Architecture, for reference, and the author writes about alignment requirements for specific platforms, where in one instance he needed all memory blocks with 128-byte alignment. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the point, and it is the entire block he was talking about, and not individual (array-) elements in the block. Yes thank you for suggesting `alignas`, I was just reading about it, though I don't think it would be a solution to attach this to every class definition in my application. If `new[]` isn't meant to be used this way, then I just misunderstood. Thanks

Comment: All those messy details are relevant when writing a custom allocator. They're not supposed to be used directly, as far as I know.

Comment: I am actually writing custom allocators atm., so I need to look into those "messy details" ;P. But if you have a good reference where I could educate myself then that would probably also work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Additional arguments to `operator new` are passed within parentheses before the type:

```
#include <new>

int* allocate() {
    return new (std::align_val_t(16)) int[40]; // 128-bit alignment
    // will call `void* operator new[](size_t, align_val_t)`
}
```

Comment: After running some tests, it seems that your example doesn't work for me. I'm using C++17 and g++ 8.4.0. Apparently the compiler disregards the customly specified alignment, both for `int`s, but also for other classes. This appears to only work with classes that are explicitly decorated with `alignas(N)`. Not even the array start position is guaranteed (likely the compiler does what it deems more efficient).

Comment: @ワイきんぐ, I cannot see an obvious reason it wouldn't work. The libcxx implementation (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/src/new.cpp#L175) calls an aligned malloc implementation with the provided alignment. If the provided alignment is less than pointer alignment, it's bumped up.